# How to correctly fork CDT Plugin so that the fork works alongside the original plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I want to fork `org.eclipse.cdt.core` to adapt some of its functionalities to my own plugin. Actually there are only a few packages that I want to fork, most of which are inside `org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser` (and subpackages). So my own plugin depends only the fork, not on the original CDT packages.

I noticed that I at least need to fork `org.eclipse.cdt.ui` and `org.eclipse.cdt.core.native` as well. I have removed all views and wizards from ui. My goal was to fork as little as possible and to reuse original plugins wherever possible.

I did: `git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git` created a new branch `fork` based on `master`.
Then I replaced every string `org.eclipse.cdt.<>' by`my.url.cdt.<>`. I renamed the import statements, the dependencies, the directory names and every occurence of`org.eclipse.cdt`. Then I imported started to import`my.url.cdt.core`and then`ui`and`native`.

I need to avoid conflicts with the original CDT Plugin, so that CDT and my Plugin can be installed next to each other. Is that possible without forking everything? I even tried to fork a whole bunch of packages (almost everything) which is not a nice solution.

So my main question is: What is the best way to fork CDT core when I only want to change functionality in a few packages?

Comment: You might be proceeding from a false assumption. What is your fork intended to do differently?

Comment: You may have better luck getting an answer to this on [cdt-dev](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev).